# HTTP POST request/response

Tags: python, json, api, post, response

when i make a POST request, how can i access value of a key(success)
i have tried the following

```
    @app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
 def vid():
 if request.method == "POST":
  firstname=request.form['firstname']
  lastname=request.form['lastname']
  email=request.form['email']
  gender=request.form['gender']
  phone=request.form['mobileno']
  city=request.form['city']
  dob=request.form['dob']
  qualification=request.form['qualification']
  marital=request.form['marital']
  occupation=request.form['occupation']
  logintype=request.form['logintype']
  password=request.form['password']
  redemptionmode=request.form['redemptionmode']
  headers={'X-AUTH': 'GJTREWFRBN8675'}
  inputs={'firstname': firstname , 'lastname': lastname,'email': email,'gender': 
   gender,'mobile':phone, 'city': city,
  'dob': dob,'education': 
  occupation,'maritalstatus':marital,'occupation':occupation,'logintype':'local','password':password,
  'redemptionmode': redemptionmode}
  r = requests.post('https://api.imaginedreality.in/api/signup',headers=headers,data=inputs)
  
  if r.success == "true":
     #some operation#
  else 
     #some operations#
```

'''
am getting an error " object response has no attribute success" but there is key called success hoe do i access its value?

this is the ideal response

```
{"success": "true","data": { },"message": "Signup Success"}
```

Comment: `r.json()['success']` BTW it might be a good idea to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use convert it into `json` to get data
remove the if-else and you can write as follows.

```
r = r.json()

if(r['success'] == 'true'):
    # Some operation
else:
    # Some operation
```

Thank you